# Static libraries and JNI

Tags: c, linker, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I have created a header file and a corresponding .c file full of functions I would like to use with a java program.  I created a JNI header file using javah.  I'm using gcc to compile my header file.  How can I link my regular c object file with my JNI static library to get a static library that utilizes my C library?  I'm using gcc to compile.

Here's an example of what I'm asking:

```
lib.h
lib.c
JNITest.h
JNITest.c (uses lib.h functions)
```

Comment: JNI libs have to be shared. Have you ever done JNI before?

Comment: you might mention whether this is for linux or windows or what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try looking at this
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

Comment: archive.org for the rescue: https://web.archive.org/web/20120301181923/http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html