# Is it possible to link a static library to Java through JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, static-libraries

Is it possible to build a HelloWorld.lib and load it to a Java application using JNI? Or it just works with shared libraries?

I couldn't find a clear answer on the JNI documentation, there's no reference to "static library".

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349093/static-libraries-and-jni

Comment: @Harlandraka I saw the question before posting, but the link is dead. Also, now it's directly question-answer instead of question-comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be a dynamic library. Fortunately, you can build a dynamic library from a static one.

Comment: Just like I thought... So I guess I'll have to recompile the static library using -fPIC flag, damn.

Comment: Or wrap it in a dynamic/shared library, avoiding the need to recompile.

Comment: Could you paste a link, how is it possible to get a shared library from a static library that hasn't been compiled with fPIC?

Comment: There's the specific question unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818921/link-static-library-without-fpic-to-shared-library-on-64bit-os

Comment: @quimnuss - Sorry, glossed over the -fPIC. Sometimes you can link static libraries into the dynamic/shared library. But with static libraries built without -fPIC, yes, looks like you have to recompile. Here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989334/shared-library-linked-with-static-library-relocation-error

Comment: I'm going back to this, how do you wrap a static library with a shared one? I'm working on it with CMake but I can't get it to work.

Comment: In general, include the static library in the linking of the shared one. Here's a specific case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649735/how-to-link-static-library-into-dynamic-library-in-gcc .

Comment: I got it working but I have a doubt. The code will be packed within a jar file, and later extracted and used in some other computer. I hope I'm wrong, but, does the jarfile have to contain both libraries in order for it to find the symbols at run-time? @Andy

Comment: When you've linked the static library into the shared library, it's in the shared library. BTW, if you're using OSGi, it can do the extraction for you, if specified in the manifest with Bundle-NativeCode.

Comment: Starting with Java 8, the library may as well be statically linked with JVM, but I guess that means you would have to compile the JVM from source, in order to include your library that can be later loaded using System.loadLibrary() without needing a .dll / .so

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 supports statically linked native libraries
http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/178

Answer (score 1):

To load a library at runtime it must be a dll (windows). If you have a static library (lib) and you have to use it via JNI you have to create a wrapper dll

Answer (score 1):

You would have to link it to the JVM, and you don't have a way to do that. That's why JNI is defined with shared libraries, not static ones.